# Why `response.json().<key>` returns unidentified value

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to fetch a json file the api in the code below ,When I convert the json response to a javascript object I expect to be able to access the value of the key `results` in that object which is an array but when i log the response in the second then chain i get `unidentified`

```
    const URLS = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=1000"
    fetch(URLS)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json().results
      })
      .then((pokemons) => {
        console.log(typeof pokemons)
        });
```

When I changed the code to this

```
    const URLS = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=1000"
    fetch(URLS)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((pokemons) => {
        console.log(typeof pokemons.results)
        });
```

it seems working fine but i don't understand why this problem is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) returns a `Promise` resolving to the result of parsing the text of the response as JSON. You cannot directly access properties on that result without awaiting the Promise with `.then` or `await` in an `async` function.